# Ansible: remove a program and say 'yes' to the command prompt?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to remove a system gem in an ansible playbook, but the command I'm running requires user input before it can complete:

```
- name: uninstall graphviz gem
  command: sudo -i gem uninstall ruby-graphviz
  sudo: True
```

When I run my playbook I find that ansible hangs when it gets to the code above. I figure it's because user input is required in order to complete this task.

So how can I tell ansible to remove the gem, and say 'Yes' to any follow-up question the OS might have for the user?

Comment: does the `gem` module hang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> RubyGems will ask for confirmation if you are attempting to uninstall a gem that is a dependency of an existing gem. You can use the –ignore-dependencies option to skip this check.

So you could just change command to `gem uninstall -​-ignore-dependencies ruby-graphviz`.

P.S. you should better use [`sudo` or `become` directives](http://docs.ansible.com/become.html) instead of sudo command.